# How to pick a random index from a nested list?

Tags: python, list, random, nested-lists

Example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [6, 7, 8]

exampleList = [a, b, c]
```

As you can see the list 'exampleList' holds other variables that are also lists, my intention is to get a random index from 'exampleList', and from that random index get a random index from that list (so a random index from either a, b, or c).

Let the variable randomIndex select a random index from a list, and randomSub select a random index from the sublist that is equivalent to the index selected by random index.

I tried:

exampleList[randomIndex][randomSub]

However, that gives me the following error:

IndexError: list index out of range.

I've also tried:

exampleList[randomIndex]

To see if that was at least working, and it did, but it returns the whole list, and I did expect that, so my question is, how do I retrieve a random index from the sublist which was also selected at random? Feel free to cook me as I'm new to programming but please give me valid insights if you're going to roast me.

Edit:

These are the functions that make the random selections in this case:
[randomIndex function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukR3V.png)

[randomSub function (ignore the [random_hint] at the end)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmByz.png)

Comment: Show us the code where `randomIndex` and `randomSub` was defined? How and where did you get these values? Without them we have no idea how or where you made a mistake.

Comment: How are you generating the random numbers? Generating a pair of indices should work perfectly well *if* they're generated properly, but you left out the most important part of the [MCVE] here.

Comment: `random.randint` gives you a random selection between two ints *inclusive*, so if you do `random.randint(0, 3)`, you're going to have 4 possibilities (0, 1, 2, 3).  If you have a list of 3 items, there are only 3 valid indices.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is `random.choice`, which directly gives you a random item from a given list without you having to do the extra work to figure out what the valid indices are, pick one, and then convert that back to an item:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> c = [6, 7, 8]
>>>
>>> exampleList = [a, b, c]
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(exampleList)
[3, 4, 5]
>>> random.choice(exampleList)
[6, 7, 8]
```

You can therefore call `random.choice` once on `exampleList` to get one of `a`, `b`, or `c` randomly, and then call `random.choice` again on whichever list you got, like this:

```
>>> random.choice(random.choice(exampleList))
2
>>> random.choice(random.choice(exampleList))
7
```

If you very specifically want an *index* rather than a value, you can use `range` and `len` to get a sequence of valid indices for a given list:

```
>>> random.choice(range(len(exampleList)))
2
>>> random.choice(range(len(exampleList)))
0
```

so you could do:

```
>>> randomIndex = random.choice(range(len(exampleList)))
>>> randomSub = random.choice(range(len(exampleList[randomIndex])))
>>> exampleList[randomIndex][randomSub]
3
```

which is the same effective result as the simpler example of two nested `random.choice` calls.

Comment: This was it. I also had another variable conflicting to the assignment of the random selection that I didn't notice, so that's on me. But it did work after implementing your reply so I REALLY appreciate your response. I also apologize to everyone reading this post as I'm really new to Stack Overflow and don't know how to build posts well. Thanks for the replies either way. All the best!